# How Can I Setup JW Player with the OVA Plugin So That VPAID ads Can Be Paused

Tags: jwplayer

I am trying to setup JW Player with the OVA plugin so that VPAID ads can be paused using the Pause button on the control bar. I was able set it up so that FLV video ads loaded from a VAST document can be paused, but I was not able to get VPAID ads to pause.

- OVA Configuration Guide
   http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/open-video-ads/13048/ova-configuration-guide

  - I use `hideOnLinearPlayback: false` to display the playback controls during ad.
  - Adding `enablePause: true` does not seem to enable Pause on the control during ad playback. It works fine when the actual content video is played.
  - The `pauseOnClickThrough: true` option doesn't pause the VPAID ad on click either.

Any suggestions as to how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The following is my OVA configuration:

```
{
    "shows": {
        "streams": [
        {
            "file": "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/wDqjiZXZ-m0JsjUy0.mp4",
            "duration": "00:00:15"
        }
        ]
    },
    "debug": {
        "debugger": "firebug",
        "levels": "fatal, config, vast_template"
    },
    "player": {
        "modes": {
            "linear": {
                "controls": {
                    "visible": true,
                    "enablePause": false,
                    "pauseOnClickThrough": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "ads": {
        "pauseOnClickThrough": true,
        "enablePause": "true",
        "displayCompanions": true,
        "companions": [
        {
            "id": "companion-300x250",
            "width": "300",
            "height": "250"
        }
        ],
        "vpaid": {
            "enablePause": "true",
            "pauseOnClickThrough": true,
            "controls": {
                "pauseOnClickThrough": "true",
                "enablePause": "true",
                "hideOnLinearPlayback": false
            }
        },
        "schedule": [
        {
            "position": "pre-roll",
            "server": {
                "type": "direct",
                "tag": "http://demo.scanscout.com/product/vastExamples/vast2VPAIDLinear.xml"
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to crack this?

Comment: Probably the VPAID-Ad does not reacts on vpaid.pauseAd()! Usually you have no influence on what the VPAID-Ad will do. Sadly, if the advertizer doesn't provide this functionality, your OVA will not be able to force it.